# List all azure-blobs with metadata into a textfile (like "dir > listmyfolder. txt" in cmd )

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

I need to get a list off all blobs we have in a azure storage account.
We have about 10'000 containers and 7'000'000 blobs.

I'm using PowerShell, but I'm a noob.
Is there a way to get this information into a text file?
I need the name and container of each blob. If I can get the size and created date it would be nice.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your version of PowerShell `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`

If you're on or above 5.1 and above, you can use [The Az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-4.7.0)

Then I assume [this cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageblob?view=azps-4.7.0) and/or [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstoragecontainer?view=azps-4.7.0)  with wildcards.

Normally I'd walk you through the exact steps, but I'm an AWS guy, and my azure experience is very limited. With that in mind, I think it would look something like this

You'd get everything you need (assuming I'm correct) and store it in a variable

```
$allTheThings = Get-AzStorageContainer -Name * | Get-AzStorageBlob
```

Then you can explore the objects, and figure out what information you need out of them, by  grabbing the first one in the array, and listing all of its properties

```
# You can do this, which will just show the properties of the object
$allTheThings[0] | Get-Member

# Or this, which will show the values of each of the properties
$allTheThings[0] | Format-List *
```

Once you figure out what information you'd like to extract, you can create a custom class, then use a foreach loop to build an array full of those custom objects, and export it to a csv doc.

```
class MySuperAwesomeClass 
{
    $PropertyIWant1
    $PropertyIWant2
    $PropertyIWant3
    $PropertyIWant4
    $PropertyIWant5
    $PropertyIWant6
    $PropertyIWant7

}

$allTheThings = Get-AzStorageContainer -Name * | Get-AzStorageBlob

$listofInfoIWant = @()

foreach($thing in $allTheThings)
{
    $myCustomObj = New-Object -TypeName MySuperAwesomeClass

    $myCustomObj.PropertyIWant1 = $thing.property1
    $myCustomObj.PropertyIWant2 = $thing.property2
    $myCustomObj.PropertyIWant3 = $thing.property3
    $myCustomObj.PropertyIWant4 = $thing.property4
    $myCustomObj.PropertyIWant5 = $thing.property5
    $myCustomObj.PropertyIWant6 = $thing.property6
    $myCustomObj.PropertyIWant7 = $thing.property7

    $listofInfoIWant += $myCustomObj
}

$listofInfoIWant | Export-Csv -Path C:\temp\azStorageInfo.csv -NoTypeInformation

# this will auto-open the newly created csv doc, comment it out to not do that
ii C:\temp\azStorageInfo.csv
```

Comment: I was really digging this post until you did the whole make an array over and over bit. It’s better to just capture the output of the foreach to a variable

Comment: @DougMaurer Can you clarify? Cuz that's pretty much exactly what I'm doing. I'm instantiating the array once, then the foreach creates a custom object, sets the values of the desired properties, and adds it to that array.

Comment: https://powershell.org/2013/09/powershell-performance-the-operator-and-when-to-avoid-it/  Each time you do that a new array is created and on large datasets it’s slow. Either do $var = foreach(){...} or use system.collections.generic.list

Comment: And https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/i7vwnv/will_this_ever_end/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf

Comment: @DougMaurer Ah, now I understand what you're getting at. True, if I was going for more efficient time-wise, I would use a list, then append to the list in the foreach. If I didn't care for readability, and wanted shorter code, I'd go for the `$var = foreach(){}` approach. Neither is the case for this answer. I'm using the simplest, easiest to understand way to go about doing what the OP wants, as they stated they are a PS newbie. It's the same reason I didn't Type the class properties. Tossing stuff like `System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]`$list to a PS newbie can be overwhelming

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to do it, so don’t teach people bad habits.